# frm-40039 can't attach library while opening form abc

Tags: oracle, plsql

Hi i new to oracle i have installed oracle forms 10 g on my windows 7 32 bit local machine,
everything    is fine whenever i try to run the form it gives error like FRM-40039 can't        attach   library while opening form.

BUT it works fine whenver i put my and fmb,fmx and .pll , .plx library in a path oracleDEVhome_1\forms but when i place all fmb.fmx,.pll,.plx file in seperate directory 
like c:\orion it

gives the error like  frm-40039 can't attach library while opening form abc

All my .pll,.plx ,.fmb,.fmx files are in the same file named orion.

The over all configeration wat that i did is,

```
1)default.env
 FORMS_PATH=c:\orion
 WEBUTIL_CONFIG=C:\DEVSUITEHOME_1\FORMS\SERVER\WEBUTIL.CFG
 PATH=C:\DevSuiteHome_1\bin;C:\DevSuiteHome_1\jdk\jre\bin\client;C:\DevSuiteHome_1\forms\server  
 forms=C:\DevSuiteHome_1\forms

2)formweb.config
  workingdirectory=c:/orion #i have put front slash as directed in formweb.cfg 

3)system environment variable
 FORMS_PATH=c:\orion
 PATH=c:\program files\java\jdk 1.8.0\bin;

4)FORMS_path variable in regedit
   FOTMS_PATH=c:\DevSuiteHome_1\cgenf61\admin;c;\orion;C:\DevSuiteHome_1\forms

5)form shortcut start in path
 start_IN=C:\DevSuiteHome_1\forms
```

please help me to fix this i have wasted two with this problem

Comment: i have an issue with reports 10g on windows 7 32bit .it gives blank internet explorer browser window when i running my report.anyone help me on this please

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of typos in your registry entry:

```
FOTMS_PATH=c:\DevSuiteHome_1\cgenf61\admin;c;\orion;C:\DevSuiteHome_1\forms
  ^                                         ^
```

If those aren't an artefact of your SO post you should correct them.

Comment: I have got a solution.what did is, whenver i opened a form builder first time,i just login to the database before  opening a form,then everything works fine no issues thanks APC.

Comment: thanks for your response APC, i have an another issue with my form builder whenever i run my sample test report10g it display blank internet explorer browser window.please help me on this.i using windows7 32bit machine

Answer (score 0):

Update the Form-Path under the registry by adding the location path to PLL & FORM file.

For example:

```
S:\development\ORACLE\DEV\SR\SRC_11g;S:\development\BITS\SourceFiles;S:\development\BITS\SourceFiles\PLL;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_FRHome1\forms;C:\Oracle\Middleware\asinst_1\FormsComponent\forms
```

At the end add all PLL library to below location which are necessary for the form.

```
C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_FRHome1\forms
```